# Multiple matchers outputting to the same field

Tags: fast-esp

We are looking for a solution to have multiple matchers which all output to the same field.

Background is that in our initial tests every matcher overwrites the output from the previous stages.

Example:

Machter A outputs "red,blue,organge" to fields meta_keywords
Matcher B outputs "soft,hard,whobbly" to fileds meta_keywords

Expected Result: After all stages the field meta_keywords contains: red,blue,organge,soft,hard,whobbly

Actual Result: meta_keywords contains "soft,hard,whobbly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having multiple matcher output to a single fields make shure the field is set as a multi value field in the index profile. The field needs to have a seperator set e.g:

```
 <field name="locations" separator=";"/>
```

With this is each matchers output is appended to the field.